# Get the previous value of textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a text box for codeigniter shopping cart's qty.

```
<input type="text" id="txt-box_one<?php echo $items['id']; ?><?php echo $items['rowid'] ?>" value="<?php echo $items['qty']; ?> " class="small-txtbox">
```

I wrote a ajax function `onmouseleave` for the textbox div.

if the user enters text box value as `4`at first and change it to `0` at second means i want to change the textbox value to `4` again.

js code:

```
function chng(id,rowid,divid,pid,price,divtotal)
{
    var inc = $('#'+id).val();
    var upd = 'update';
    if(inc < 1)
  {
    // $('#'+id).val('1');
    var retVal = confirm("Are You Sure to Remove This Item From Baskets?");
   if( retVal == true ){
      var inc = 0;
   }
   else {   { $('#'+id).val(1); var inc = 1; }   }

  }

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "qty="+inc+"&row="+rowid+"&upd="+upd+"&pid="+pid+"&price="+price,
        url: "<?php echo base_url('grocery/text')?>",
        success: function(html){
        $('#'+divid).html(html);
        if( retVal == true ){
        location.reload();
        }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I think calling the original value via ajax is overkill; you can alternatively store the original value on data attributes `<input data-originalvalue="4"></input>`

Comment: add your initial value in a `hidden field` and then its just need some `if else` to do what you are trying.

Comment: and where is your js code?

Comment: added..Now You see.. @karlingen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this jQuery approach also

```
var count;
$("#count").on("keyup",function(){
    if($(this).val() == 0)
        return;

    count = $(this).val();

});

$("#count").on("blur",function(){
    if($(this).val() == 0){
        $(this).val(count);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/40s0q1oy/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
function getValue() {
    var val = $.trim($("#quantity").val());

    val = parseFloat(val);
    val = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;

    return val;
}

$("#quantity")
.on("keyup", function() {
    var val = getValue();

    if (val) {
        $("#quantity").data("old-value", val)
    }
})
.on("blur", function(){
    var val = getValue();

    if (val == 0) {
        $("#quantity").val($("#quantity").data("old-value"));
    }
})
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BKtSV/76/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare in this way,

```
if(inc < 1)
```

you will have to parse it into an integer, so use

```
if(parseInt(inc) < 1)
```

Comment: In that case, I would prefer  `parseInt(inc, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery with something like :

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#qty").change(function(){ 
        if($(this).val()<=0){            
            $(this).val($("#qtyold").val());
        }
        var ch_val=$(this).val();
        $("#qtyold").val(ch_val);
     });
  });
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="qty" value=""  />
```

Please let me know if it's working